# Is there a way to fit only vertically or horizontally in svg-pan-zoom.js library

Tags: svgpanzoom

This is not obvious from the documentation (if you can call `README.md` documentation ;) ), but the [svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) library probably supports (only) vertical/horizontal fit, though how? Best fit is already supported through `fit` method and works fine.

The method called `contain` is probably the one to use, yet when I call it sometimes it does one and sometimes the other.

I know I can probably do this myself and/or contribute to this nice OSS, just checking if the support is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can do this yourself, though it requires a few lines of code ;)

The `contain` method **is** the ticket, but note that if you need dedicated buttons for vertical/horizontal fit, you need to calculate which of the two methods - `fit` or `contain` you want to use.

In order to do so, you need to find out if the SVG is "portrait" or "landscape" - meaning, if the width is smaller than height (former) or not (latter).

This is easy to do, you just call `panZoom.getSizes()` (where you're obtained `panZoom` by calling `svgPanZoom` function) and check `viewBox.width` vs `viewBox.height`. If width is larger, you're in landscape - you get the picture (pun intended).

So, if you're in landscape and want to fit horizontally, it's the same as best fit, so you just call `fit`. If you want to fit vertically, call `contain`.

Similarly, if you're in portrait and want to fit vertically, this is the same as best fit, so just call `fit` otherwise call `contain`.

Comment: Thank you, what an "ATHN" solution !